# Turning on speaker while incoming call is active is not working on Android 10

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a default dialer app for my client, calling functions are happening perfectly but am facing this isssue,
here is my code,

```
AudioManager mAudioManager=getApplicationContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(view.isActivated());
```

I tried all the solutions given in stack overflow, none of them are worked for me.
Please help me out with this.